# use django model to get db information from json request

Tags: json, django, postgresql

I'm using Django 1.9.6. I have a simplified User model which corresponds to the data in the database:

```
class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
    email = models.EmailField(_('email address'), unique=True)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(_('active'), default=False,)
```

and I would like to the user information (`is_active`) from the `email`. My simplified User view is as follows:

```
def settings(self, request, **kwargs):
    self.method_check(request, ['post'])

    data = self.deserialize(
        request, request.body,
        format=request.META.get(
            'CONTENT_TYPE',
            'application/json; charset=UTF-8'
            )
        )

    as_user = request.as_user

    if as_user:
        return self.create_response(request, {
            'success': True,
            'is_active': as_user.is_active,
        })

    return self.create_response(request, {
        'success': False,
    })
```

And the request body is a json that looks like:

```
{
  "asUser": "user_email@company.com"
}
```

I'm not sure exactly what to do where I currently have the line:

```
as_user = request.as_user
```

to get the other information about the user in the model class.

Comment: You need to give more details. What class is this `settings` function from? What is `self.deserialize` there?  If, as seems likely, that's deserializing the request body, why don't you access `data['asUser']`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand well, you want to retrieve the user object associated with the email sent in request body:

```
as_user = models.User.objects.get(email=data['asUser'])
```

That will raise an `models.User.DoesNotExist` exception if email can not be found.

Comment: Not exactly what I needed (`as_user = User.objects.get(email=data.get('as_user'))`), but close enough that it got me there. Thanks!